# C++, Integer and Char array conversion trouble

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I have the `char` array:

```
char* chararray = new char[33];
```

and the `int`:

```
int exponent = 11111111;
```

What I want to do, but am confused as to how, is: input the values of `exponent` into `chararray`. With the restrictions that `exponent` has to take up the 2nd to 9th values of `chararray`. `chararray` will be all 32 0s,and I want it to become 0xxxxxxxx0000....00, the x's being the 8 digits in `exponent`.

Furthermore, no build-in conversion functions like atof or atoi. I also want to avoid using Floats or doubles not that you'd really need to.

Note, this is for making IEEE754 32bit values to get some understanding.

Will edit for additional details or clarification if needed.

Comment: Loop, `%` and `/` operators are your friends there.

Comment: There's really no need at all for `new` here.

Comment: also note that `x+'0'` is equal to `'x'` for all 1-digit integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this after initializing the array with `'0'`:

```
for(int i=9; i>=2; i--) {
        chararray[i] = (exponent%10) + '0';
        exponent = exponent/10;
    }
chararray[32] = '\0';
```

Comment: You're printing the digits into `chararray` backwards ;-). Easiest to start at the right and work back towards the left (i.e. `chararray[10-i] = exponent % 10 + '0';`)....

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited the post! Checked the test code with `11111111`, that's why couldn't catch it :).